Design not showing proper result in Omnet++ after defining the network in NED file
I followed a tutorial and entered the source code for the NED file but did not get the intended result.
simple Txc10
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
        input in[];  // declare in[] and out[] to be vector gates
        output out[];
}

network Tictock10
{
    @display("bgb=259,198");
    submodules:
        tic[6]: Txc10;
    connections:
        tic[0].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[1].in++;
        tic[0].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[1].out++;

        tic[1].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[2].in++;
        tic[1].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[2].out++;

        tic[1].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[4].in++;
        tic[1].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[4].out++;

        tic[3].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[4].in++;
        tic[3].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[4].out++;

        tic[4].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[5].in++;
        tic[4].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[5].out++;
}

this is the source code in the NED file.
Expected:

Actual:


Remove the line @display("bgb=259,198"); and start your simulation.

Yes. Your screenshot is from the IDE, while the expected one is from the runtime environemnt. The two thing displays different data in different ways. The IDE does NOT expand the module vectors while the runtime does. That's why you see only a single module vector icon in the IDE, but you can see the individual module instances in the runtime. This is normal.
